# How to update an array of objects when variable state changes?

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredFeed(allFeed.filter((obj) => obj.name === { selectedName }));
  }, [selectedName]);
  ...

  return (
    <>
     {filteredFeed.map((e, i) => (
        <FeedByUser e={e} key={i} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

It only works when I hard code:

```
setFilteredFeed(allFeed.filter((obj) => obj.name === "John Doe"));
```

When `selectedName` state changes, the `FeedByUser` component should also change.

Edit: typo - key

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need a `useEffect` or to reset the state in this case. You can directly apply the filter to your results. Remove the `useEffect` and change your rendering to:

```
<>
 {allFeed.filter((obj) => obj.name === selectedName).map((e, i) => (
    <FeedByUser e={e} key={key} />
  ))}
</>
```

It will filter the data at each state change without the overhead of a `useEffect`.

Also be careful, I copied your code using key in the FeedByUser component but key is not defined in the snippet you showed.

Comment: That's good to know, but still only works when I hard coded it. I could print out the value and see as selectedName as John Doe but component doesn't react. Again only when I hard coded "John Doe" then I could see the component displayed.

Comment: `const [selectedName, setSelectedName] = useState("John Doe");` This method will also printout John Doe, but component wouldn't react either. It is only succesful when `filter((obj) => obj.name === "John Doe"))`

Comment: Corrected on my answer, didn't check this part of the code which was not related to the useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Syntax error - unnecessary brackets:

```
<>
 {allFeed.filter((obj) => obj.name === *{* selectedName *}*).map((e, i) => (
    <FeedByUser e={e} key={key} />
  ))}
</>
```

Answer:

```
<>
 {allFeed.filter((obj) => obj.name === selectedName).map((e, i) => (
    <FeedByUser e={e} key={key} />
  ))}
</>
```